# Keycloak Integration with Spring boot, using custom login page (Signing in without keycloak's default login page)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

> What I am trying to achieve:
>   User can sign in with our project's sign in page (within project) without redirection to keycloak's default login page. I have configured spring security with Keycloak it is working fine **But user logs in through keycloak's default login page**
>
> My questions: how can i achieve this feature where I will get token from Keycloak using REST API like

```
   curl \
  -d "client_id=id-client" \
  -d "username=username" \
  -d "password=psw" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_secret=secret" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myRealmName/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

> and give access to my Spring Project (Spring security whatever)

**As far as i understand I can log in using jquery in my front end and obtain token, eventually pass to spring security or whatever**

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have found good solution to this problem which I am going to explain step by step:
First of all, if you want to use custom login page you have two options:
1. Modifying the existing keycloak themese like login/registration/passwordupdate which can be found via directory of /keycloak/themes/*
2. This can be a bit tricky - which can be achieved by modifying AuthenticationProvider of Spring Security in your project.

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http
            ?.authorizeRequests()
            ?.antMatchers("/**")?.authenticated()
            ?.and()
            ?.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider)
            ?.formLogin()
            ?.loginPage("/login")
            ?.successHandler { request, response, authentication ->  redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/main")}
            ?.permitAll()
            ?.usernameParameter("username") //the username parameter in the queryString, default is 'username'
            ?.passwordParameter("password") //the password parameter in the queryString, default is 'password'
            ?.and()
            ?.logout()
            ?.logoutUrl("/logout") //the URL on which the clients should post if they want to logout
            ?.invalidateHttpSession(true)
            ?.and()
            ?.exceptionHandling()
    }
```

> MyAuthenticationProvider you should override this spring security class
>
> One more thing I have asked in above question, what if i use rest api to access to spring project, in this case you should implement KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: if anything makes no sense, you can contact me anytime))

Comment: I did not understand how to 2nd solution. Can you give more details?

Comment: What's about the access type in the Keycloak client? Do you set "confidential" oder "bearer-only"?

Comment: @Aliy can you guide me on this scenario where I have a fronted application in Angular with login page and I want to send login request to my server then from there I want to send a rest login request to keycloack with client_credentials flow using username and password and get the access token and then send back the access token to my frontend app.